# What is this large white Canon telephoto lens in a 1990 magazine ad for the EOS 1?

Tags: lens, canon

I am trying to identify this Canon Telephoto Lens seen on an ad at the back of an old copy of National geographic from Feb. 1990:

[image]

I have tried to look for it on Google, but I can't find one that is exactly the same number of rings (2 it seems) and same position of the metal strap clip above the white knob.

Comment: Please describe the lens in the question title. Otherwise, it could be about literally any Canon lens.

Comment: Maybe if I am asking to identify it, is because I actually have no idea what it is and cannot say anymore about it that it is a lens? Or should I say "help me identify this 300mm f/2.8L lens? Not sure what you mean...

Comment: Yes, describe in as much detail as possible. That way, other people can find it by searching, and just as importantly are less likely to find it by accident when looking for a totally different lens.

Comment: ok, do you have a suggestion? should it all be in the title or also the body of the Q.?

Comment: It's important for the title to be unique enough to stand out in a lost of similar titles. The body can go into more detail.

Comment: Looks like you edited it, great job! Sorry I didn't get what you meant, thanks for making the edit! Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not a Canon shooter, nor have I owned Canon gear before.*

This appears to be a 300mm ƒ/2.8L USM (non IS) lens, produced from 1987 to 1999. The best collection of images, review, and information about this particular Canon lens I could find is: [300mm ƒ/2.8L at kenrockwell.com](http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/300mm-f28.htm).

Searching for this threw me off, because if you go to the [Lens Hall of the Canon Camera Museum](http://www.canon.com/c-museum/en/lens-ef-series.html), the image of the [EF300mm ƒ/2.8L USM listed there](http://www.canon.com/c-museum/en/product/ef270.html) is of the image-stabilized (IS) version of the lens. ([Google image search of 300 2.8L USM IS](https://www.google.com/search?q=canon%20300mm%202.8L%20USM%20IS))

[image: http://www.juzaphoto.com/shared_files/recensioni/canon_300_f2-8l.jpg]

Comment: Gah. Beat me by a few seconds! :D  I was spelunking [ebay listings](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Experience-the-Best-for-Sports-Nature-CLAd-Canon-EF-300mm-f2-8-L-USM-III-/141880257517), since Rockwell's shot is from the other side, and, well, he's _Rockwell_....

Comment: @inkista yeah, I really searched around for another site to link to, and I don't like to use that site as a reference. *But*, in this case, archeologically (in internet terms), it's pretty thorough. =/

Comment: Actually, the one thing I trust Rockwell on is historical lens data--he is more of a camera gear collector than a photographer imho. It's his "reviews" that tend to be... more Rockwellian.  I'm just sad it was too new for the [mir.com.my](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/eos/EF-lenses/index.htm) guys to have it listed.

Comment: Canon has made a mk ii of this lenses, their website talks about it. https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/telephoto/ef-300mm-f-2-8l-is-ii-usm